# How to get NSE spot minute ticker data from google finance api?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, google-finance-api

In previous, I could get all minute ticker from google finance api all like below url

[http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=NIFTY&x=NSE&i=60&p=1d&f=d,c,o,h,l](http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=NIFTY&x=NSE&i=60&p=2d&f=d,c,o,h,l)

But now google providing only 1 interval data for a day as the daily summary. I think Yahoo is also stopped to providing minute ticker data. Any other API is there for getting spot minute ticker data other than https://www.alphavantage.co/?

Answer (score 0):

I got another URL for getting minute ticker data.

https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices?q=RELIANCE&x=NSE&i=60&p=1d&f=d,c,o,h,l

Comment: Google sends back a very polite turn-down.  Apparently no longer working.